# Connecting to Gmail from Python

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I've been trying to connect to my Gmail account using python. `imap` is enabled.

```
import imaplib

imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
# also tried imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com"), doesnt work.
```

Traceback is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 1202, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 1217, in open
    IMAP4.open(self, host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 248, in open
    self.sock = self._create_socket()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 1205, in _create_socket
    sock = IMAP4._create_socket(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 238, in _create_socket
    return socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 435, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/socket.py", line 426, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host
```

Comment: can you make sure you have access, and check with `traceroute` ? you could be behind a firewall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host` means is what it say: you can't get to that machine from your machine.

You can test that from outside of Python by opening up a terminal/DOS prompt and typing this:

```
ping imap.gmail.com
```

It's possible that this is actually a name lookup error, and you're somehow getting a bad address for `imap.gmail.com`. So, just to be sure, check by IP address too:

```
ping 74.125.129.108
ping 74.125.129.109
```

If `ping` works, you can check whether your router is for some reason just blocking TCP access to the host, e.g., with:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com
```

If it's working, this should either hang for a long time, or give you a connection-refused error; if it gives you a no-route-to-host error, it's the same problem you're seeing.

It's also possible that your router is specifically blocking port 993. You can test this too:

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
```

If it doesn't come back with something like "Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com", same problem here too.

At any rate, once you've verified that this is a system or network configuration problem, not a programming problem, go ask for help with your system on the appropriate site.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I do see `connected to gmail..`

Comment: @3zzy: Then you _don't_ have the same problem. Create a new question, with all the relevant information; you can include a link to this question or answer if you think it will help. And make sure to explain that you can connect with telnet from the same machine.